# MediaPlayer error: pause called in state 64

Tags: android, media-player

I am using a `MediaPlayer` in my `Activity`.

When I hit the back button, I get this error:

```
09-20 19:44:16.540: E/MediaPlayer(1822): pause called in state 64
09-20 19:44:16.540: E/MediaPlayer(1822): error (-38, 0)
```

**Code**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        if (mp!= null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop(); 
        }

        Intent intentstart = new Intent(X.this, Y.class);
        intentstart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentstart);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If I use `mp.pause()`, it's working fine. Why?

Comment: Yes: if (mp!=null) mp.pause(). Apart from that super.onPause();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's illegal to pause a stopped `MediaPlayer`, and according to that error message that sounds exactly like what you're doing.

I suggest changing your `onPause` such that it does not try to pause the stopped `MediaPlayer`.

Perhaps:


```
    if(mp!= null) {
       if(mp.isPlaying()) mp.pause();
    }
```

Actually don't do this, I just found this in the docs:

> Note that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state and vice versa happens asynchronously in the player engine. It may take some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying(),

You should maintain a variable locally to check if you've already stopped the `MediaPlayer`, and then test that for whether or not you should call `pause()`.

Comment: What if I use .pause everywhere, and don't use .stop() at all?

Comment: I can't immediately think of any reason why it wouldn't work, though I'm not an expert on mediaplayer.

Comment: I solved it by using mp.pause() everywhere (if mp.isplaying()) and not using mp.stop() anywhere.

Answer (score 19):

I used pause and seekto method to reset the player.

```
player.pause();
player.seekTo(0);
```

Answer (score 8):

I have come here looking for answers, though the responses above were useful in other things, they did not solve my problem...

BUT ... I managed to fix the problem:

changing 
`mediaPlayer.stop();`

to

`mediaPlayer.reset();`

helped me get rid off the `error( -38 , 0 )`

thanks again for pointing out the problem :)

Comment: thanks. Do not forget to rate the answer by clicking the "Up Arrow" next to it. I am glad I could help :)

Comment: This works but when you do `mediaPlayer.start()` after that, you get another error. @Goran's answer works well for me with no errors

Answer (score 2):

After facing an issue in starting the media player after stopping it, 
i got an exception and mp was an able to start again, 
then when replacing `mp.stop()` with `mp.reset()`
it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Even I've faced the similar problem with same error.

I used `mplayer.pause()` instead of `mplayer.stop()`