# Toggling state play,pause,stop in Android

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am creating a Media player with two buttons start/pause and Stop button, When I start playing for first time it works fine. But when I try to start after once stop I need to click on start/puase button twice.

I don't understand this behaviour.

Below is my onclick code :

```
public void click(View view){
    int id = view.getId();

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH);
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    switch(id){
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        synchronized(this){

            if(!isStarted){
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                isStarted=true;
                mPlayer.start();
                System.out.println("Play");

            } else{
                System.out.println("Pause");
                isStarted = false;
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
        return;
    case R.id.btnStop :
    synchronized(this){

        if(mPlayer!=null){
            System.out.println("Stop");
            mPlayer.stop();
            isStarted = false;
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        } 
}
```

And here is my layout xml file :

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:onClick="click" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="click" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Aman

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if directly adressing your issue, but shouldn't you add a `break;` at the end of each switch case? Would like to put that in a comment but I don't have enough rep yet, sorry.

Comment: there is already return statement in case...although I tried with break as well but no success...

Answer (score 0):

Problem I found with `mplayer.stop();`  I just replace stop to pause and its works, I edited little in your code, have once look:

*Within onCreate:*

```
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ThirdActivity.this,R.raw.test);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

*onClick Event*

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            Log.d("^^^^^^", "flag=" + isStarted);
            Log.d("^^^^^^", "clicked");
            synchronized (this) {

                if (!isStarted) {
                    add.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                    isStarted = true;
                    mPlayer.start();
                    System.out.println("Play");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Pause");
                    isStarted = false;
                    add.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                    mPlayer.pause();
                }
            }

            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    System.out.println("Stop");
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    isStarted = false;
                    add.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Even check below link.

[MediaPlayer:Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12520154/646806)

Answer (score 0):

Should  call `mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH);` only in `Idle` state and call it in other state return error.
And Should call `mPlayer.prepare();` only in `Initialized` and`Stopped` states.

I think read this link from android developer for use media player will helping you.[------MediaPlayer-----](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

In your case you shoud check if media player is stopped before call mPlayer.prepare(); and remove mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH); from `onClick()`.

Hope this helped you.