# Android mediaplayer music pause sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a button that starts certain music if it's not being played already. If yes then clicking this button should stop the music. Next time after you click it will start from the beginning again.

The problem is sometimes when I click button while it's playing it doesn't work and music continues to play.
I don't see why.

Here is the code responsible for it.

```
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.song);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp1.isPlaying()==false){
                mp1.seekTo(0);
                mp1.start();
            }
            else 
                mp1.pause();
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Answer is found in this comment.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12520154/2277445

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityName.this , R.raw.song);
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!mp1.isPlaying()){
            mp1.seekTo(0);
            mp1.start();
        }
        else 
            mp1.pause();
    }   
});
```

do not use Equal to  operator in these type of cases

Comment: It didn't help. Still happening.